# Render component from already existing html string

Tags: reactjs, render, dynamic-html

I want to implements creation of a component for already prepared html string and styling object using React. We have the data as follows:

```
const obj = {
    block1: '<div>TEST-1</div>',
    block2: '<div>TEST-2</div>',
};
const styling = {
    block1: { fontSize: '12px', color: '#123456' },
    block2: { fontSize: '18px', color: '#153426' },
};
```

As a result, I'd like 2 blocks to be created:

```
<div style="font-size:12px; color:#123456;">TEST-1</div>
<div style="font-size:18px; color:#153426;">TEST-2</div>
```

I've already tried 2 npm modules to implement this idea (without styling):

- ReactHtmlParser - creates a component from any html string
- JsxParser - can render jsx + component at the same time

But I get the same error al the time:
*Component.render(): A valid React element (or null) must be returned. You may have returned undefined, an array or some other invalid object.*

My render looks like this:

```
render() {
    customBlock = getBlock(obj, styling); // markup objects
    return(
        <Component1 />
        { customBlock }
        <Component2 />
    );
}
```

Maybe someone could help to understand why component from the getBlock function return something that can't be rendered?

```
getBlock = (block, styling) => {
    let markup = '';
    for (let element in block) {
        if (block[element]) {
            markup += block[element];
        }
    }
    return <JsxParser bindings={{}} components={{}} jsx={`${markup}`} />
    // OR
    // return ReactHtmlParser(markup);
}
```

P.S. other components are normal objects {props...}, but that dynamic components have the same structure, but additionaly covered in object 'body' {body:{props...}}. So ReactElement.isValidElement can't check $$type property of the object because of this 'body' wrapper =(

Comment: You should return one element, an array or a fragment depending on the version of React you are using

Comment: I'm using react 15.6.1. But it returns me a single component... Idk what makes it bad...

Comment: `(
        <Component1 />
        { customBlock }
        <Component2 />
    )` is not a single element

Comment: @BoyWithSilverWings The main thing is that without customBlock everything is rendering perfectly. But what problem can be in rendering customBlock?